# fatal error : Index out of range when i use remove(at: indexPath.row) to remove item form Array

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, swift4

```
if checkedItems[indexPath.row] {
    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    basketArray.append(theArray[indexPath.row])
} else {
    cell?.accessoryType = .none
    basketArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
```

`fatal error : Index out of range when i try to remove(at: indexPath.row)`

I try `tableView.reloadData()` but it did not work. How can i fix this problem? `basketArray` is an empty array.

Comment: "basketArray is an empty Array" **What do you expect then?**

Comment: if basketArray is empty it is normal to have an Index out of range. You can't remove an element when none exists.

Comment: I first i append something to the array. and when  i remove i get the error! basketArray is an array that i want to select all the checkmark! and deselect when i uncheck! it works at the begin.but then i get the error

Answer (score 1):

try below, it should resolve crash of fatal error

```
if checkedItems[indexPath.row] {
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            basketArray.append(theArray[indexPath.row])
        }else{
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
            if basketArray.count > indexPath.row {
                basketArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this fixes your crash, it will not produce the behaviour you intended. When you append an item to the array they will be appended first at index 0, then 1, then 2 etc. so you cannot remove the item at indexPath.row. You need to search in basketArray to find the index of the object at indexPath.row, then remove the object at that index

Comment: This fix my crash but indeed I did not solve my problem! I some times uncheck a cell but it does not remove the content from the array! TegRa you know how to fix this!I am new at swift!